# Formatting Time without colon in Azure Data Factory (Java SimpleDateFormat)

Tags: java, azure, simpledateformat, azure-data-factory

I'd like to format a timestamp like yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH-mm-ss as using colons causes issues when reading through ADF.

I'm writing it in ADF which uses Java SimpleDateFormat - can't seem to find anywhere in docs about writing a timestamp like this.

Is it possible and if so, how?

Comment: `System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH-mm-ss").format(new Date()));`

Comment: are you doing this in a data flow?

Comment: @MarkKromer Yep!

Comment: Something like this?

toString(toTimestamp('2016-01-13T00:12:00', 'yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss'),'yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss')

Or you can keep the dashes ... I wasn't sure if you wanted dashes or colons based on the way your question was worded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the ADF built-in [Date Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#date-functions) , your requirement can't be implemented so far.

However, you could use [formatDateTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#formatdatetime) to convert your `datetime` into `String`.Then you could use [substring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#string-functions) to assemble your desired format.

Answer (score 0):

In Azure DataFlow, for individual items of time/date, use as follows :

```
year(currentDate())
month(currentDate())
dayOfMonth(currentDate())
hour(currentUTC())
minute(currentUTC())
second(currentUTC())
```

Concat and use as required.